# How to fix jQuery DOM using Object problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to set an id in html to a string set that is located inside a property inside an object using jquery. But for some reason, when I do run the program, the jquery script doesn't work. I tried setting the html DOM code inside the document.ready, and also tried to run the code inside a function that runs after other events are activated but nothing changed. Help me fix this problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var testObj = {
    exampleText = "Hello world"
  };


  $("#test").html(testObj.exampleText);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Your syntax is invalid, which you should have been able to see by checking the console for errors. Key-value pairs in an object should be separated by `:`, not `=`

Comment: As pointed above, just use `var testObj = {exampleText: "Hellow world"};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error.
use var testObj = {exampleText: "Hello world"}; instead.

Comment: Thxs m8 great help